# Clipboard.GetText() Copy Data From Excel

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code:

```
    Dim ClipBoardArrayData() As String
    
    ClipBoardArrayData = Clipboard.GetText().Split(Environment.NewLine)
    CilpboardColNo = ClipBoardArrayData(0).Split().Length
    CilpboardRowNo = ClipBoardArrayData.Length
```

this using to copy data from Excel,
"CilpboardColNo" has to be return number of cells copied, but if there is a space in the cell text will consider as 2 cells

any help in this issue please, how to return the Number of cells copied,

many thanks

Comment: Can you post an example string for the first row. ClipBoardArrayData(0)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to get your desired result

```
Dim CilpboardColNo = ClipBoardArrayData(0).Split(vbTab).Length + ClipBoardArrayData(0).Split(" "c).Length -1
```

First one is for actual coumn count and second one is space count as you desired.